# Asp .NET Core MVC: jQuery Ajax,, async await and Session data managing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, session-variables, jquery-ajax

Quick summary:
In ASP.NET Core (Net 5) MVC project, I need a way to keep aligned and synced various controls in a single page (grids, dashboards, all in the same page),
with some session variables that hold their data (I know, bad design decision, but for now I am not allowed to decide). These controls interact and change session data through ajax request to the MVC controllers.
What is the best way/pattern to do this?

Long detailed version:
I have to port an old ASP.NET WebForms to port to an ASP.NET Core MVC application with Razor pages.
I have a page with various grids which acts like this (also in the old application):

when controllers starts grids check if datasource for them is in HttpContext.Session["key"], and if it is, it takes from session, else, it takes it from db and put it in session, so that, the next time it reloads, it takes it from the session.

Now the critical part.
One of the grid has buttons that open popups and modify data also for other grids interacting directly with the session, so the other grids reload data from the session keys.

The base concept is, that every modification to the grid data that happens in this page lives in session variables (every grid has it's own) and an actual call to db to get the data happens only the first time that the page loads in the session. After the page data edit is finished, you save and it all gets committed to the database and the session variables are freed.

My question is:

I modify data from grid and call a jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ManageSession", "SessionManagement")',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            data: postData,
            success: function (result) {
                showMessage(result.responseText, result.success ? 'success' : 'error', 3000)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                showMessage(result.responseText, 'success', 3000)
            }
        });
```

this is the controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> ManageSession([FromBody] ManageSessionModel manageSession)
        {
            try
            {
                var Grid1Dataaa = this.HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Grid1Data>>("SessionKeyTest1");
                var Grid2Dataaa = this.HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Grid2Data>>("SessionKeyTest1");

                switch (manageSession.actionType)
                {
                    case "add":
                        try
                        {

                            return Json(new { success = true, responseText = $"{manageSession.ids.Length} elements have been added" });
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "An error happened while trying to add the selected deviations" });
                            throw;
                        }
                    case "remove":
                        try
                        {
                            return Json(new { success = true, responseText = $"{manageSession.ids.Length} elements have been removed" });
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "An error happened while trying to remove the selected deviations" });
                            throw;
                        }
                    default:
                        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "There are no items selected to remove or add" });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

My doubt is how ajax manages the async controller action.

If I call the ajax and the user clicks the button mutiple times what it happens?

The session gets modified multiple times concurrently?
I don't know if jquery ajax calls the controller and the control immediately to the javascript and fires multiple request allowing multiple threads to modify session?

Or ajax enqueues the async calls and executes one after the other?

I don't know if the ajax success/error event is merely based on the HTTP 200 return even if the controller fires an error.

I also thought about managing the controller return requests with
return Ok();
return BadRequest(....);

since it may be a better way to manage the ajax error/success thing.

I've also thought about setting ajax async false to make it syncrhonous.

Can anyone suggests me the better pattern to manage this with sessions and ajax in MVC?

The customer request is to keep using sessions so avoiding them it's not really an option.

Comment: From js, you could disable the button when you first send the request, and enable it again in success and error functions.  Just a thought

Comment: @hijinxbassist And that's perfectly a good decision. But, when it happens that $.ajax() returns success/error? I mean If I call the controller (async Task<JsonResult> ManageSession), does $.ajax() immediately returns to success because it's async, so the HTTP Call immediately returned a HTTP200 (and so, the control immediately returns to JS but the controller code it's still executing), or it will finish executing all the controller code completely, then it will return to $.ajax() success/error and all the controller code will be completely executed?

Comment: It will execute and only hit success/error on return from the controller.

Comment: thanks this clears out a lot of issues in the design